# SELECT all rows by WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following query which works (without the "WHERE stats.dt" part). I get all users with their data.

My problem is that this query of course results in rows ONLY with users that have stats.dt > $timestampnow-$maxdays_data). But I need ALL users but their values of SUM(upload) or SUM(download) need only to be fetched when stats.dt is larger than tstamp-maxdays. The other rows with values of upload and download where stats.dt is smaller than what I need, can be ignored.

An example would be that the user with nodeid 2 would not be selected because his dt is too small. I do want the user to be selected but just not with data or upload values (they can be 0).

The stats table looks like this

```
nodeid |    dt      | upload | download
----------------------------------------
1      | 1381699533 | 345345 | 42324234
1      | 1382899152 | 7575   | 574234
1      | 1380699533 | 764534 | 7235232
2      | 1372899152 | 71455  | 124123
```

I don't know where to start looking how to solve this so maybe somebody out there can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

```
SELECT b.id, b.lastname, b.name, c.balance, a.maxdebt, b.warndata, b.warndownload, b.warnupload, b.warndebt, b.cutoffdata, b.cutoffdownload, b.cutoffupload, b.cutoffdebt, b.data, b.download, b.upload, b.warning, b.access, b.cutoffstop
FROM (
SELECT customers.id AS id, SUM(tariffs.value) AS maxdebt
        FROM tariffs
        LEFT JOIN assignments ON tariffs.id = assignments.tariffid
        RIGHT JOIN customers ON assignments.customerid = customers.id
        GROUP BY id
) a
JOIN (
SELECT customers.id AS id, UPPER(lastname) AS lastname, customers.name AS name, SUM(stats.upload+stats.download) AS data, SUM(stats.download) AS download, SUM(stats.upload) AS upload, customers.cutoffstop, warndata, warndownload, warnupload, warndebt, cutoffdata, cutoffdownload, cutoffupload, cutoffdebt, nodes.warning, nodes.access
        FROM customers
        LEFT JOIN nodes ON customers.id = nodes.ownerid
        LEFT JOIN stats ON nodes.id = stats.nodeid
        LEFT JOIN customerwarnings ON customers.id = customerwarnings.id
        WHERE stats.dt > ($timestampnow-$maxdays_data) 
        GROUP BY id
) b ON a.id = b.id
JOIN (
SELECT customerid, SUM(cash.value) AS balance
        FROM cash
        GROUP BY customerid
) c ON b.id = c.customerid
```

Comment: You can use SQL HAVING for it. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a brute force way of doing it. It can almost certainly be simplified, but without knowing more about the table and foreign key structures it's hard to be sure.

What I've done is replace `sum(stats.download)` with `sum(case when stats.dt > ($timestampnow-$maxdays_data) then s.download end)` and similarly for upload. I've also changed the join on b to be an outer join:

```
Select
    b.id, 
    b.lastname, 
    b.name, 
    c.balance, 
    a.maxdebt, 
    b.warndata, 
    b.warndownload, 
    b.warnupload, 
    b.warndebt, 
    b.cutoffdata, 
    b.cutoffdownload, 
    b.cutoffupload, 
    b.cutoffdebt, 
    b.data, 
    b.download, 
    b.upload, 
    b.warning, 
    b.access, 
    b.cutoffstop
From (
    Select
        c.id,
        sum(t.value) as maxdebt
    From
        tariffs t
            left join
        assignments a
            on t.id = a.tariffid
            right join 
        customers
            on a.customerid = c.id
        Group by
            c.id
    ) a left outer join (
    Select
        c.id,
        upper(lastname) as lastname,
        c.name,
        sum(s.upload + s.download) as data,
        sum(case when stats.dt > ($timestampnow-$maxdays_data) then s.download end) as download,
        sum(case when stats.dt > ($timestampnow-$maxdays_data) then s.upload end) as upload, 
        c.cutoffstop,
        warndata, 
        warndownload, 
        warnupload,
        warndebt, 
        cutoffdata, 
        cutoffdownload, 
        cutoffupload, 
        cutoffdebt,
        n.warning,
        n.access
    From
        customers c
            left join
        nodes n
            on c.id = n.ownerid
            left join
        stats s
            on n.id = s.nodeid
            left join
        customerwarnings w
            on c.id = w.id
    Group By 
        c.id
    ) b 
        On a.id = b.id
        inner join (
    Select
        customerid, 
        sum(cash.value) as balance
    From
        cash
    Group By
        customerid
    ) c 
    on a.id = c.customerid
```

Comment: That worked great! Thanks. Indeed I think it can be simplified, but my  sql knowledge is only what the internet has to offer me :S I'll extend my post later with what my tables look like and it would be great if you'd like to have a look at it.